# Mongodb unwind and match VS match and unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking to optimize the MongoDB performance by minimizing the number of records to unwind.

I do like:

```
unwind(injectionRecords),
match("machineID" : "machine1"),
count(counter)
```

But because of huge data unwind operation takes a lot of time and then it matches from unwind.
It unwinds all the 4 records then matches machineID from result and give me count of it.

Instead I would like to do something like :

```
match("machineID": "machine1"),
unwind(injectionRecords)
count(counter)
```

So, it would match records having machineID and unwind only 2 instead of 4 and give me the count of it.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Here are sample docs,

```
{   
   "_id" : ObjectId("5981c24b90a7c215e4f166dd"),
    "machineID" : "machine1",
    "injectionRecords" : [ 
        {
            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:45:04.779+05:30"),
            "endTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:45:07.763+05:30"),
            "counter" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:45:24.417+05:30"),
            "endTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:45:27.402+05:30"),
            "counter" : 2
        }
    ]
},
{   
   "_id" : ObjectId("5981c24b90a7c215e4f166de"),
    "machineID" : "machine2",
    "injectionRecords" : [ 
        {
            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:46:04.779+05:30"),
            "endTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:46:07.763+05:30"),
            "counter" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "startTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:46:24.417+05:30"),
            "endTime" : ISODate("2017-08-02T17:46:27.402+05:30"),
            "counter" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is certainly possible to order an aggregation pipeline with (1) match then (2) unwind so the answer to your question might depend on whether **your specific match** is actually applicable to the data before it is unwound. Can you update your question to include an example document and your current unwind and match stages?

Comment: @glitch can u post optimized query for my question?

Comment: @RicardoRocha Please do not use code formatting for words like 'mongodb'. [For more information look at this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254995/4244993)

Comment: @jmattheis thank you for the tip :)

Comment: OP was likely running a very old version (3.0 or earlier) as MongoDB will automatically reorder these two stages when it's safe as of 3.2 (released Nov '15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return a count of `injectionRecords` for a given `machineId`. I *think* this is what you are asking for.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {machineID: 'machine1'}},
    {$unwind: '$injectionRecords'},
    {$group:{_id: "$_id",count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Of course, this query (where the unwind takes place before the match) is functionally equivalent:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$injectionRecords'},
    {$match: {machineID: 'machine1'}},
    {$group:{_id: "$_id",count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

However, running that query with explain ...

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$injectionRecords'},
    {$match: {machineID: 'machine1'}},
    {$group:{_id: "$_id",count:{$sum:1}}}
], {explain: true})
```

... shows that the unwind stage applies to the entire collection whereas if you match before unwinding then only the matched documents are unwound.

Comment: thanks alot @glitch. I wasn't quite sure about the stages of query execution, but '{explain: true}' was of lot of help.

Comment: not sure what version you checked with but for several years now explain would show that the $match will automatically be swapped in front of $unwind when it's safe to do so.  
> db.collection.aggregate([     {$unwind: '$injectionRecords'},     {$match: {machineID: 'machine1'}},     {$group:{_id: "$_id",count:{$sum:1}}} ], {explain: true})
{
 "stages" : [
  {
   "$cursor" : {
    "query" : {
     "machineID" : "machine1"
    }, ...
   }
  },
  {
   "$unwind" : {
    "path" : "$injectionRecords"
   }
  }, {$group: etc...